# Is a cube vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is simple. The cube contains zero vector.
I'm not sure about this, but I think it doesn't create vector subspace. Because a finite cube is not closed to the sum and scalar multiplication. Am I right?
In case the cube is infinite, then it creates vector space $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ (?)

Comment: No bounded subset is a vector subspace.

Comment: Ok, sorry for such a stupid question but I wanted to make sure I'm right. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @EduardoLonga No bounded subset *except* for the singleton $\{0\}$.

Comment: Certainly not a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, but it could be mapped reasonably onto a finite vector space like $\mathbb F_2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard definitions of a subspace and by a cube, I take it you mean a typical cube with 6 vertices for example at $(\pm1, \pm1, \pm1)$, then it is evidently not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

For a subspace S we have the property:

If $u \in S$ and $t \in \Bbb R$ then $t.u \in S$ wich is not true for a bounded subset like a cube. To see that just take a value of $t$ as big as you can such that $t.u$ goes outside of the subset.